# How do I highlight a cell in Excel when all its content is contained in another column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column (column A) that contains a list of text and another column (column B) that contains a smaller list, which is the values that I actually care about.  Is it possible to only highlight cells in column A if all of its contents is listed in column B?  If so, how?

```
  A                   B
Apple               Apple
Peach               Pear
Apple, Pear         Plum
Apple, Grape        Kiwi
Apple, Pear, Kiwi        
Watermelon, Grape
```

So in the above example, I would like to highlight A1, A3, and A5 because all of the contents is listed somewhere in column B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following formula for the Conditional formatting:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),$B:$B,0)))
```

[image]

---

If one does not have FILTERXML then they can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," &$B$1:$B$4&",",","&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")&",")))=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

Noting that the range `$B$1:$B$4` must be the size of the lookup values without any blanks

Comment: Sorry Scott, I can't seem to get this to work.  No idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @ScottCraner - appreciate the help.  Unfortunately, it's not doing anything.  I can't upload a screenshot but it's not highlighting any cells.  I've tried my best to validate everything and even set up a new sheet to mirror all of the sample data and get even get that to highlight

Comment: what version are you using? @mgreenfi

Comment: Excel for Mac v16.34 @ScottCraner

Comment: Do you have `FILTERXML` in that version?  If not see edit. @mgreenfi

Comment: @ScottCraner - That was it, FILTERXML isn't supported on a mac.  The edited formula worked perfectly and saved me a ton of time.  Thank you!